# Is it possible to use elementary OS from a live USB while persisting its data?

Tags: system, usb-drive

Can I use live version from [usb](/questions/tagged/usb) and save the things done during the session? Or does it simply come back to original state every time it is opened from live USB?

Answer (score 4):

elementary OS does not officially support being used as a persistent live USB. However, the following method can be tried at your own risk:

---

It is possible to use third-party software to have your settings stored in the live USB. Any changes you make to the system—for example, saving a file to your desktop, changing the settings in an application, or installing a program—will be stored in the overlay file. Whenever you boot the [usb](/questions/tagged/usb) drive on any computer, your files, settings, and installed programs will be there.

Ubuntu can be used with **live use with persistent storage**. And elementary is based on Ubuntu so it will work too.

Please follow these steps,

1. At first download the iso of the operating system and another software called [Linux Live USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/home).
2. Install Linux Live USB Creator. Insert the USB drive you want to use into your computer’s USB port and launch the “LiLi USB Creator” application you just installed.
3. Select the USB drive you want to use in the “Step 1: Choose Your Key” box.
4. Provide your downloaded ISO file. Click the “ISO / IMG / ZIP” button under “Step 2: Choose a Source”, browse to the .ISO file on your computer, and double-click it.
5. Use the options in the “**Step 3: Persistence**” section to select how much space your want to use for persistent storage on the USB drive. Drag the slider all the way to the right to select the maximum amount of storage.
6. You’ve now configured all the settings you need to configure. To create your live USB drive with persistent storage, click the lightning icon under “Step 5: Create”

Above instructions are grabbed from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) which shows *How to Make a Persistent Ubuntu USB Drive on Windows*. However, the process is **quite same**.

Comment: It did not work for ElementaryOS. Once the ISO file is selected the app disable the option to select a persistence space on the USB.

Comment: You can see this in LiLi homepage "This project is not maintained anymore. Read more."

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linux Live Usb Creator( [www.linuxliveusb.com](http://www.linuxliveusb.com) ) but it only supports elementaryos-stable-i386.20130810 with persitence

See here :- [www.linuxliveusb.com/en/supported-linuxes](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/supported-linuxes)